# Using a variable instead of a parameter index with a JDBC prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc

In many programming languages something like this is possible for prepared statements:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT id FROM Company WHERE name LIKE ${name}");
statement.setString("name", "IBM");
```

But not with java.sql.PreparedStatement. In Java one has to use parameter indices:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT id FROM Company WHERE name LIKE ?");
statement.setString(1, "IBM");
```

Is there a solution to work with string variables like in the first example?
Is "${.*}" not used somewhere else in the SQL language, or are there any conflicts? Cause then I would implement it by myself (parsing the SQL string and replacing every variable by "?" and then doing it the Java way).

Regards,
Kai

Comment: Hey kd304, I wonder why you didn't leave your message as answer instead of using a comment. Cause I think it's the way for me to solve that problem.

Comment: @tokel: I wasn't sure about your question being theoretical or not and my comment does not really answer your typed question.

Comment: Even though ... thank you :-)

Comment: "In Java one has to use parameter indices:" - actually, it doesn't look like that in your sample. In Java, one *cannot even* use parameter indices in the SQL string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As kd304 mentioned in the comment to my posting, this is a very nice solution if you don't want to incorporate another 3rd party library (like Spring) into your project: [Javaworld Article: Named Parameters for PreparedStatement](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-jdbc.html)

Comment: Link no longer works...

Comment: @XelaNimed that's why link-only answer aren't accepted anymore, but it might have moved to [this](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077706/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html?page=2). Looks at least similar to the old page.

Answer (score 30):

Standard JDBC PreparedStatements don't have this ability. Spring JDBC provides this functionality through [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-NamedParameterJdbcTemplate).

Comment: Thanks for the very good solution. The problem for me is that it will be part of another open source framework and I don't want to import so much code there. Otherwise I would have used your solution :-)

Answer (score 6):

Using a raw PreparedStatement, this is not possible, as you say. It is possible with CallableStatement, but that requires a stored procedure rather than just a SQL statement.

ORM layers like Hibernate also provide named parameter substitution, and Hibernate also allows you to execute native SQL, bypassing the OR mapping functionality completely.

So if you were really keen to use named parameters, you could employ Hibernate as a way of doing this; you'd only be using a tiny fraction of its functionality.

Comment: Forget my idea, @laz has a much better one.

Comment: I think Oracle JDBC driver supports calling regular SQL statements with named parameters when using CallableStatement, not just for procedures. PostgreSQL says "Not yet implements" (postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar)

Comment: That's so sad, as DBMSsupports this, at least SQL server does,
and JSBC intrnaly creates named parameters, like following:
`@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 varchar(8000),@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 smallint,@P4 nvarchar(4000),@P5 int`