# How can handle reserved character in SQL query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, object-oriented-database

I want to read data from a table but I got a error because the value I want to compare may contain a word like this: abcd l'jdmd

I try it like this:

```
String s = "select ref(ad) from adresse_tab ad where ad.ort='"+rs.getString(11)+"' and ad.plz='"+rs.getString(13)+"' and ad.land='"+rs.getString(14)+"'";
        
PreparedStatement stmt5 = nsdCon.prepareStatement(s);
ResultSet rs5 = stmt5.executeQuery();
```

The query could look like this:

```
select ref(ad) 
  from adresse_tab ad 
 where ad.ort='Frankfurt am Main' 
   and ad.plz='65301' 
   and ad.land='Deutschland' 
   and ad.strasse='almundo l'tare '
```

So the problem in this query is this comparison:

```
ad.strasse='almundo l'tare '
```

How can I handle reserved character in SQL query?

Comment: Use preparedStatement.setString .

Comment: what you just got is an example of sql injection, consider using parameters instead of string concatenation, this will escape any special characters in your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please avoid creating a SQL query with supplied parameters using string concatenation. Instead you can continue using PreparedStatement, but use placeholders for the actual param values, and use the statement's `set<X>()` methods for setting params. Here's [official Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps) on this.

> You must supply values in place of the question mark placeholders (if
>   there are any) before you can execute a PreparedStatement object. Do
>   this by calling one of the setter methods defined in the
>   PreparedStatement class. The following statements supply the two
>   question mark placeholders in the PreparedStatement named updateSales:
>
> updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
>   updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey()); The first argument for each of
>   these setter methods specifies the question mark placeholder. In this
>   example, setInt specifies the first placeholder and setString
>   specifies the second placeholder.

For your case:

```
String s = "select ref(ad) from adresse_tab ad where ad.ort=? and ad.plz=? and ad.land=?";

PreparedStatement stmt5 = nsdCon.prepareStatement(s);
stmt5.setString(1, rs.getString(11));
... and so on
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) (and for added clarity of named bind variables you can use an [OraclePreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html)):

```
String s = "select ref(ad) from adresse_tab ad where ad.ort=:ort and ad.plz=:plz and ad.land=:land";
PreparedStatement st5 = nsdCon.prepareStatement(s);
OraclePreparedStatement ost5 = (OraclePreparedStatement) st5;
ost5.setStringAtName("ort",rs.getString(11))
ost5.setStringAtName("plz",rs.getString(13))
ost5.setStringAtName("land",rs.getString(14))
ResultSet rs5 = st5.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Good point. Named parameters are much more readable, and maintainable. I wish Java would provide them out of the box rather than having to rely on [external deps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1097855/1782481).

Answer (score 1):

You should not add your query parameters directly to the query string. Use a [Prepared Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead and pass the query parameters there. See also [Does the preparedStatement avoid SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333015/does-the-preparedstatement-avoid-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of prepared statements is to use parameters within your query so values can be automatically escaped:

```
String s = "select ref(ad) from adresse_tab ad where ad.ort=? and ad.plz=? and ad.land=?";
PreparedStatement stmt5 = nsdCon.prepareStatement(s);

stmt5.setString(1, rs.getString(11));
stmt5.setString(2, rs.getString(13));
stmt5.setString(3, rs.getString(14));

ResultSet rs5 = stmt5.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ad.strasse='almundo l'''tare '
```

Comment: The problem is how can i handle this,  if i do not know in advance that this comparison could happen .

Comment: If you're using a variable, oracle will take care of it and you won't have an issue - but you had hard coded.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to complement it with context, detailed information and/or code examples. The _Post Answer_ button should be used only for **complete answers to the question**.