# Use a value in MySQL query in multiple lines without a variable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have this mysql query that uses the same value I'm passing, 3 times over.

```
select p.*,
       ROUND(sum(unitsPerBlock * blocks) / datediff(date(now()), date(?)), 2) as avg
from batches b
inner join products p on b.productID = p.id
where (
          select sum(b1.availableQty)
          from batches b1
          where b1.productID = p.id
            and b1.addedDate between date(?) and date(now())
      ) = 0
and b.addedDate between date(?) and date(now())
group by b.productID
order by avg desc
```

Is there any way to make this query without me having to type the below

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, date);
preparedStatement.setString(2, date);
preparedStatement.setString(3, date);
```

And just use this

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, date);
```

Comment: Can you show are is the `preparedStatement` created? -- the actual variable declaration/assignment

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1097957/5640649

Comment: @lealceldeiro is there any way that I could use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate here? I'm not using Spring atm

Comment: It seems no, but I'm not a regular user of JDBC, so I might be missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select p.*,
       ROUND(sum(unitsPerBlock * blocks) / datediff(CURRENT_DATE, input.parameter), 2) as avg
from batches b
inner join products p on b.productID = p.id

CROSS JOIN (SELECT date(?) AS parameter) AS input

where (
          select sum(b1.availableQty)
          from batches b1
          where b1.productID = p.id
            and b1.addedDate between input.parameter and CURRENT_DATE)
      ) = 0
and b.addedDate between input.parameter and CURRENT_DATE
group by b.productID
order by avg desc
```

Comment: As a regular dev reading the code-only answer posted here, I'd ask: where does `input.parameter` come from? where's `CURRENT_DATE` coming from? If you could add an (at least a minimal) explanation to this post, it'll help better future readers.

Comment: @lealceldeiro *I'd ask: where does input.parameter come from?* ?? You do not see? There is only one `?` char in the query text... and `preparedStatement.setString(1, date);` will replace this placeholder with provided value. *where's CURRENT_DATE coming from?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date

Comment: I saw the `?` in the code you posted just after searching for it in my browser just because you mentioned now, which tells the answer is not self-explanatory. If it helped the OP, great, that's the main purpose of posting here. IMO, the answer can be improved, thing I tried to encouraged you to do. But I won't waste my time with someone who does not take well a good recommendation/critic. Peace out!